# swiping a SeekBar and Stop it on UiAutomation for Android

Tags: android, scroll, seekbar, android-uiautomator

i'm designing a automation for android by UiAutomatorTestCase class.
**I want to control SeekBar swiping and TestView on UIAutomator**.

for instance, if SeekBar is moved to left. TextView is changed negative number. so if the number is "40". I want to stop the swiping.

I could swipe the seekbar to left direction but can't stop it.

```
UiScrollable seekbar = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.test:id/setting_item_child_menu_seekbar"));
seekbar.swipeLeft(200);
```

please help me how can I stop that SeekBar when some test of TextView is "40".

Comment: Why are you testing a number like 40? Wouldn't it be easier to test the absolute highest and lowest? i.e. 0 and 100? That way you can guarantee that sliding the seekBar all the way to either end will have a reliable number to check against

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative way to control seekbar, since I also found the standard methods hard to use because of some problems, so here it is:

```
private void clickSeekbar (float position) {
    while ((seekBarUiObj2 = mDevice.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE+":id/seekbar"))) == null) {
        mDevice.click(200,200);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Rect rect = seekBarUiObj2.getVisibleBounds();
    mDevice.click(rect.left+5/*pixels*/+(int)((rect.right-rect.left-10/*pixels*/)*position), ((rect.top+rect.bottom)/2));

}
```

The trick is to click on the device on the desired location on the seekbar.
It works.
The whlle loop makes sure the seekbar is on screen, if not tap the screen on some location, which makes seekbar to appear.
Then calculate the location to be clicked according to desired position.
Only if your seekbar is very thin like 1 or 2 pixels it might not work.

Comment: The float position parameter should be 0f for start, 1f for end and 0.5f for middle of the seekbar.